# Want to increase Java Heap Size to 4GB+: Physical Memory 8 GB, JVM 64-bit

Tags: java, memory, jvm

I want to run a memory intensive package on a web server.

Current computer's settings are... 
Windows 7 64 bit
64-bit JVM
RAM: 8GB

When I try to run eclipse with 
-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m

I get:

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.

From posts that I read, it seems like I should be able to use more than 4GB of memory. 
When I ran the code, I was able to max out the memory at -Xmx1200M and still be able to run the code. But for what I want to accomplish, I need to use more memory. How can I increase the memory size here?

---

Thank you everyone. The issue was that I was using a 32-bit version of JDK. I was able to run memory at 2GB after switching the JDK to the 64 bit version. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure it really is 64-bit JVM running -- and not an imposter! A 32-bit JVM is still subject to 32-bit sizes, but will run fine on a 64-bit Windows.

Comment: I think it is a 64-bit JVM running. When I run java -version, I get

java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: What does help -> about eclipse tell you ?

Comment: The problem was that I was using a 32-bit version of JDK. Thanks!

Comment: @Ji Mun Consider answering your own post and marking it as solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that I was using a 32-bit version of JDK.

Thank you, and thank you to Mister Smith for pointing out that I should answer it and mark it as solved.