# JVM error after increasing Java heap size

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse java heap size set to **-Xms512m -Xmx512m** .But one of my program execution failed to due to "Out of memory error Java Heap space".

I tried to increase java heap size with

```
eclipse.exe -vmargs -Xms512m -Xmx1024m 
Result:JVM Error
eclipse.exe -vmargs -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m 
Result:Again JVM error
```

Also, i have modified -Xms and -Xmx in eclipse.ini but i was not successful.Same error here too.

My machine has 3 GB RAM with Windows XP. And i have only one eclipse installation.
Java version is 1.7.

Here is the stack trace of the error on eclipse

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(Unknown Source)
at java.io.StringWriter.write(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToStream.processDirty(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToStream.characters(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToUnknownStream.characters(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToUnknownStream.characters(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformIdentity(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
at businessrule.implementation.WriteToXML.printtoXML(WriteToXML.java:53)
at businessrule.implementation.WriteToXML.UpdateKnowledgeBase(WriteToXML.java:41)
at businessrule.implementation.ExecuteRule2.<init>(ExecuteRule2.java:133)
at businessrule.implementation.BusinessRules.main(BusinessRules.java:81)
```

Comment: Is your program a web application? Are you using a server inside eclipse?

Comment: I got error while writing data to xml.

Comment: But is your program a web application running in tomcat, jboss, etc...?

Comment: You need to change the Xmx and Xms values in the "Run Configuration" of the program you are running.

Comment: It is not a web application.It's a java program writing data to xml.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to add memory to the eclipse. 
Add memory in the run configuration of your program.
For that, right click your project -> run As -> run configuration.
under the java Application/executer , go to arguments.
There you can specify any VM Arguments.

[click here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/launchers/arguments.htm)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the JVM wants contiguous memory for the heap, which is a problem for older OSses like XP.

If you already have Eclipse running, chances are there is not enough contiguos memory left.

Solutions:

1.) Run your program from the command line while Eclipse and other memory hungry apps (Office? IE? consult your Task Manager to find out) are **not running**.  Note that the maximum heap size in Windows XP will still be something like 1200M.

2.) Upgrade to Windows 7 or 8

3.) (my preferred one) Change OS and use Linux for development.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Xmx and Xms parameters affects to the memory that Eclipse use but not for the java applications that you run or debug inside Eclipse.

To add more memory to a particular Java Application in run or debug mode you have to go to Run -> Run Configurations (or Debug Configurations):

[image]

Comment: Even in run configuratiion it accepts -Xmx512m.But program fails with same error.If i give -Xmx1024 i getting JVM error here too.

Comment: In that case it looks like your program is using more memory. You can profile your application using VisualVM (that comes with the Oracle JDK). What is the size of the xml files that your are reading?

Comment: This is the error i got when i give -Xmx1024m is -----Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap

Comment: The size of XMLl file is 22MB. By the way i am not reading xml.I am just taking xml element and appending text to xml element

Comment: Delete the Xmx and Xms configuration from your eclipse ini. Because if you have only 3GB and you are using 1024 for eclipse and 1024 for the application you dont have enough RAM to execute both java apps.

Comment: deleted the Xms and Xmx from eclipse.ini.Eclipse is running with only 512m now.Even in application run configuration has 512m

Comment: How much free Ram memory do you have before running the application?

Comment: i checked in Task Mnager: PhysicalMemory                              Total    3139516                                                      Available  489100

Comment: So you can not run the application because you dont have enough memory

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to set max and min heap for your JVM

```
java -Xms256m -Xmx1024m YourClassNameHere
```

Answer (score 0):

Another problem that you could be experiences is you are using a 32bit JVM. Look at this:

[Want to increase Java Heap Size to 4GB+: Physical Memory 8 GB, JVM 64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276381/want-to-increase-java-heap-size-to-4gb-physical-memory-8-gb-jvm-64-bit?rq=1)

Comment: i am using windoes XP 32 bit and JRE also 32 bit

Comment: So you should look another approach because you can not handle this amount of memory in the gc with a 32 bits system.